# Nuxt - Understanding slotted component structure and usage

Tags: vue.js, frontend, vue-component, nuxt.js

The Nuxt component structure is looking as below:

```
components
├── modal
│   └── Modal.vue      (Slotted component called in CoolModal.vue)
│   └── CoolModal.vue  (Depends on Modal.vue)
├── item
│   └── ItemDetails.vue (Independent)
│   └── ItemList.vue    (Independent)
```

When I uses `<CoolModal>` component in a page, the app raises an error stating:

```
Unknown custom element: <CoolModal> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

Which can be fixed by adding:

```
<script>
import CoolModal from '~/components/modal/CoolModal.vue'

...

export default {
  components: { CoolModal },
  ...
}
</script>
```

I've tested that I can make a call to the rest of the components listed in the structure above without `import ... from` help, except for the `CoolModal` component.

Why do I need `import ... from` help to be able to use `CoolModal` component but not for the other components?

To complete the context, following is my `components` property value in `nuxt.config.js`:

```
components: [
  {
    path: '~/components',
    pathPrefix: false
  }
],
```

Comment: which version of Nuxt are you using? I tried your file structure and it does not show me that error in Nuxt v2.15.7!

Comment: @hamid-davodi I am on `"nuxt": "^2.15.0",`. Hmm.. Im not sure what I've done differently, but the error says it can't find the component when I make use of a slotted component within. I wonder if that's due to loading the components asynchronously, but I can't find any indicator to support the theory.

Comment: I'm not sure, but according to the [Nuxt documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/components) the name of folders may influence on the component calls (in Nested Directories section). So I suggest to change the name of folders or the version of Nuxt to see that the problem is solved or not.